# MS-SQL In statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select a, b, c from table where a in (1, 2, 3)
```

What if the list is in a column?

I try this will error:

```
Select a, b, c from a in b
```

Sorry for not clear my question.

It's not about **join** or **in (select b from table)**

Column b type is nvarchar, data is a list, like this '1,2,5'

Column a type is int.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are your tables? What are their columns? What is the expected result of the query that you are unable to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question, this is what you want:

```
SELECT
    a,b,c
FROM
    tblA
WHERE
    b LIKE CAST(a as nvarchar) + ',%'
    OR b LIKE '%,' + CAST(a as nvarchar) + ',%'
    OR b LIKE '%,' + CAST(a as nvarchar)
```

That should do it.

Comment: No it wouldn't.  Notice the placement of the commas.  Already got that covered.  Booyah.

Answer (score 1):

Many answers pointing in the right direction, but I think this one will really work:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM table
WHERE ',' + b + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(a as varchar) + ',%'
```

You can speed this up by enforcing B starts and ends with a comma.  Or even better, normalize the database and move the column B to its own table with a one-to-many relation.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, a column is normally of one of the so-called "scalar" data types: numbers, date/time, strings -- see e.g. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx). If you explain better in what sense you got "a list" into column `b`, and how, e.g. show us the `CREATE TABLE a` statement, we can maybe help you better!

Answer (score 0):

See [Need SQL Query Help, matching a stored procedure list parameter against individual columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813124/need-sql-query-help-matching-a-stored-procedure-list-parameter-against-individua/813352#813352). It shows how to write a UDF that will take your "list" column and return a table that you can use to join against the one you're selecting from.

Answer (score -3):

I think you want to JOIN the tables?

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.ID=b.ID
```